# gcc don't compile c

Tags: c, linux, gcc, g++

My OS is Ubuntu Linux 20.04

I reinstalled gcc and some libraries
I didn't change anything in the system, I don't know what could have happened.

Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: unknown type [0x13] section `.relr.dyn'
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 when searching for                /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/bin/ld: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: unknown type [0x13] section `.relr.dyn'
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 when searching for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the command you used to build this? And while you are at it, what command you used to "reinstall gcc."

Comment: I use gcc main.c -o main

Comment: "Reinstalled gcc and some libraries I didn't change anything in the system" - for legacy reasons, Linux doesn't always have a clear distinction between programming languages and the OS. In particular, `libc` is used by both C and the OS. `skipping incompatible /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` points to a system-wide problem.

Comment: The root problem here seems to be `/usr/bin/ld`, which is called from `gcc` after compilation.

Comment: Is it possible to solve the problem without resorting to any rough methods, for example, reinstalling the system?

Answer (score 1):

You've updated `gcc` and `libc`, but not `binutil`. This will update `ld` to understand `.relr.dyn`.

Comment: It didn't help sudo apt install build-essential binutils